# Cannot access Seam Components within JAR from WAR in [JBOSS 7.1.1.FINAL and SEAM 2.2.1.CR2]

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, seam, jndi, jboss-seam

Problem: I have an ejb-jar-1.jar which defines EJBs and Entities. The project structure is listed below. During deployment all EJBs are successfully bootstraped > started and their JNDI locations are printed in a log file. There's a class in my WAR file which needs to access a NAMED QUERY defined on an Entity which resides inside `ejb-jar-1.jar`. When this piece of code is run it throws an illegalArgumentException saying NAMED QUERY cannot be found. On a different note I also cannot get reference to SEAM components that were started when `ejb-jar1.jar` was deployed. I printed the JNDI tree from app-war.war file and it does not have any JNDI resources from `ejb-jar-1.jar`. So, I believe this is a context issue where JNDI resources available in `ejb-jar-1.jar` cannot be seen from app-war.war.

Any suggestions on how to access JNDI resources available in `ejb-jar-1.jar` from `app-war.war`?

Deployement Info

```
* JBOSS 7.1.1.FINAL
* Uses seam framework: jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar
* Uses Hibernate 3.4.0.GA
```

main-ear.ear

```
|__META-INF
|   |____jboss-deployment-structure.xml
|   |____application.xml
|   |____jboss-app.xml
|   |____MANIFEST.MF
|__lib
|   |____somejar.jar
|   |____somejar.jar
|__ejb-jar-1.jar
|__ejb-jar-2.jar
|__jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar
|__commons-lang-2.4.jar
|__commons-codec-1.1.jar
|__jasypt-1.6.jar
|__app-war.war
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.codec"/>
            <module name="org.picketlink" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.picketbox" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.javassist" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.dom4j" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.javassist" slot="1" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="app-war.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.ejb-jar-1.jar" />
            <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.ejb-jar-2.jar" />
            <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
    <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.jasypt-1.6.jar" />
    <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.commons-codec-1.1.jar" />
    <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.commons-lang-2.4.jar" />
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">
    <description>myapp</description>
    <display-name>myapp</display-name>
    <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
    <module>
        <ejb>ejb-jar-1.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>ejb-jar-2.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>app-war.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/app</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but oh well...for EE6 you need to use JNDI portable syntax, eg. add following annotations to all beans in the secondary module

```
@JndiName("java:app/NameOfModule/NameOfBean")
```

Comment: DaveB, thank you - this led me to solve my own similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

Think you need seam.properties in your jar in META-INF

Comment: I already have `seam.properties` in META-INF of the `ejb-jar-1.jar`